# Close Python Thread To Prevent Memory Leak

Tags: python, multithreading

How to I close a Python thread in order to make sure that everything in memory within a thread is cleared from memory? Currently, I have a list of threads that I join in the following manner:

```
for t in threadlist:
    t.join(5)
```

These threads were originally created looping over a list of arguments to pass to each thread with `myfunc` which appends results to a list:

```
threadlist = []
for r in arglist:
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(r,))
    t.daemon = True
    threadlist.append(t)
```

When I look at what's in memory with `pympler` all manner of things in the function called by the thread remain in memory after this executes. I need it to garbage collect as it would if I called `myfunc` normally without threading.

Comment: As long as your `threadlist`exists all  memory Referenced within `myfunc` can't be freed.

Comment: The threadlist is contained in an object as `myobj.threadlist`. I am deleting that object wtih `del myobj` and still having this problem.

Comment: `del` does not guarantee _garbage collecting_, check any References created. This could also a returned​ object.

Comment: Is there a way to force garbage collecting the threads? I don't think anything from the threads is outside of the object deleted.

Comment: There is a module `weakref`, handle such situations. https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

Comment: I see how weakref can create weak references to an object, but I don't understand how to garbage collect the actual objects in the thread.

Comment: Let's start to Debug. Does `pymbler` show the _**Reference Counter**_ of the `objects` in Question?

Comment: The objects being deleted were contained within an object function. Moving them outside of that object function and into a regular function allowed garbage collecting to occur following delete.

Answer (score 3):

> Resolved in comments:
>
> The objects being deleted were contained within an object function.
>   Moving them outside of that object function and
>   into a regular function allowed garbage collecting to occur following delete.
>   Michael